# Error MT1006 Container creation failed

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Im trying to debug my application on a physical iPhone 4s i bought. The iphone is completely empty, i did the startup config and no more.
My VS2015 is connected to my Mac build host, where the iPhone 4s is connected too as well. As far as i know are the certificates installed and correct.
The iPhone shows up in VS2015 as an device for debugging

Macbook Pro running 10.10.5 (Yosemite) and Xcode and Xamarin studio. Windows 8.1 installed on a VM on that Mac, with VS2015 and the total Xamarin package.

Full error is:

```
error MT1006: 
Could not install the application '/Users/*placeholder*/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/*placeholder*/*placeholder*/bin/iPhone/Debug/*placeholder*.app' on the device iPhone van *placeholder*: Container Creation Failed Error (error: 0xe8000041).
```

I replaced some personal details with *placeholder*

This error appears in building with VS2015 as well when building with Xamarin Studio on the Mac

I could not find information on how to solve this issue, so i hope people can help me.

Maarten

Comment: Only a full rebuild helps solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this thread again, and liked to share my answer.

The problem invoking this error was due to the iphone being downgraded in iOs version, despite the technical division told me it was brand new. Can't remember the exact versions anymore though.
Once the iPhone got back updated to the (then most recent) iOs version, it all started working without problems.

Answer (score 6):

To fix all deployment errors on new phones i have a very good method.

Open xcode, create a new iphone project (choose a non empty template), build and deploy it on the phone using xcode. Fix any errors if xcode asks for it.

xcode will fix your provisioning profiles and may do changes on the phone to make it available for deployment.

After a succesful deployment using this dummy ios app using xcode, try deploying your real app again with VS2015.

Comment: Gonna try this in a moment

Comment: What this suggestion did do was force me to use xCode with the device. Straight away xCode told me that the dvice had a version of iOS that was greater than the version supported by my installed version of xCode. Thank you Softlion, thank you xcode

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that there are no earlier versions of "Installed Apps" in Windows/Devices/Installed Apps section of xCode.  My version is 8.3.2.

Any older app versions that didn't get properly deployed due to a crash or missing provisioning profile will prevent the deployment of an app to the target device.

Using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.
The specific related error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error MT1006: Could not install the application 'Your Path' on the device 'iPad': AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe80000be (kAMDMismatchedApplicationIdentifierEntitlementError).

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how to fix the MT1006 error, when trying to Free Provision a Xamarin app to an iOS device in Visual Studio.

I happen to be using Visual Studio 2017 on a PC, with a Macbook Pro running XCode 10.1, and an iPad, which is running iOS 12.1. But I am *sure* this will work for others.

- Plug iOS device in by cable to the Mac.
- Open XCode on the Mac
- Go to **Window** > **Devices and Simulators**
- Click on the new device and allow XCode to install something on the
  device to allow debugging.
- In XCode, go to **File** > **New** > **Project…** (or open up the previously
  created app)
- At the top of the screen, change the selected device for the test app
  to publish to, to the new device.
- Click **Play** in the top left of XCode. (This will installed the test
  app on the device, but will fail).
- On the new device, go to **Settings** > **General** > **Device Management** >
  **[your email address]**
- Click the '**Trust [your email address]**', then the Trust button.
- Back in XCode, press **Play** again.  (The app should run fine.)

In Visual Studio, you should now be able to push Xamarin apps to this device.

The other 'thing' to remember, is that the Free Provisioning certificates/licenses only last about 6 days, and then you have to re-open XCode and let it reset the licences.  XCode does this itself, and then in VS2017, you can simply disconnect from the Mac, reconnect and it should be ok again.

Answer (score 0):

#### MT1006 Could not install the application '*' on the device '*': *.

This error is usually related to an issue on the device itself. Steps that we go through:

1) Reboot the iOS device (number one issue for us)

2) Make sure the device screen is not locked

3) Make sure that there is enough free storage on the device

4) Reboot the Mac AND the iOS device

5) Try a different USB cable (glitchy cables are a nightmare, try a different cable, really, trust me, wasted hours one day after someone dropped the phone with the cable attached ;-)

(This error also pops up concerning when running OS-X as a virtual machine and not assigning dedicated USB port(s) to the VM)

Comment: 1) Done. Nope. 2) Device doesnt lock, screen is always on. 3) As i stated, Phone came out the box, did the initial setup and nothing more. So there is enough space available. 4) Done. Didnt work either. 5) Ill have to check for another Cable, but i dont think its wonky as it is a new Cable. Thanks for Your help, do you have more suggestions?

Comment: hmmm... try another cable and a different USB port... after that I'm stumped, sorry

Comment: Already tried different usbport, trying another Cable shortly

Comment: @MaartenHeebink  Also since you are running Windows as a VM, shutdown the VM (Fuson vs Paralles) and try it from Xamarin Studio just to be sure the the USB port is not being mucked up (either in limbo as "non-assigned" to either Windows or OS-X or assigned to Windows...). Assuming if you startup iTunes on the Mac it sees the device but double check if you have not...

Comment: @MaartenHeebink I asked around (different client) and someone recommended to test the phone with iTunes (if you have not), connect and do a backup AND restore...

Comment: I make sure the iPhone doesnt tunnel to vmware fusion, iPhone gets connected to iTunes and xcode sees it as well. Connection is all ok

Comment: Xamarin studio sees it too by the way

Comment: Silly question, but have you made sure that you added the device to your provisioning profile?

Comment: This is clearly a huge beta product on Microsoft's part. The sheer number of steps and configuration required to pull this off is ridiculous. I'm calling it DOA, give them another 18 months to get this out of beta (aka version 3)

Comment: @Craig ? This issue has nothing to due with Xamarin, this is/was a device issue....

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was unchecking the 'Enable device-specific builds' in the iOS Build tab of the .iOS file. After rebuilding the solution the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to a higher version of iOS running on the connected device than the version supported by XCode/MacOS.

For me the app ran just fine with VS2017 against MacOS High Sierra (XCode 10.1) via USB on an iPhone running iOS 12.4.1. However it gave **"Error MT1006 Container creation failed"** while trying to run the app on another device which ran iOS 13.1.

Well, we figure out that with MacOS High Sierra (XCode 10.1) the max one can build for is iOS 12.x device via USB. For devices with higher version of iOS, one needs either MacOS Mojave or MacOS Cataline (ad higher version of XCode). To compliment that you may also want to upgrade from VS2017 to VS2019.

Hope this helps.